# Paramiko bug: SSHClient.connect() method hangs when the peer is unreachable even if I set the 'timeout'

Tags: python, timeout, paramiko

Here is a python code snippet that uses paramiko:

```
import paramiko

sshClient = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshClient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
sshClient.connect(_peerIp, username=_username, password=_password, timeout=3.0)
```

As soon as I run the script, I also unplug _peerIp's network cable. And connect() method hangs. Even though the timeout is 3.0, it has been 10 minutes and it still hangs.

(I think the TCP connection was established in a split second and I unplugged the cable during the ssh establishment)

So, do you know any workaround for this? My script will run at a manufacturing factory and it must not hang in such a scenario and handle it properly.

EDIT:

It just gave an exception:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/client.py", line 327, in connect
    self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/client.py", line 438, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_publickey(username, key)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/transport.py", line 1234, in auth_publickey
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 163, in wait_for_response
    raise e
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

Ok, at least it eventually raised an exception but I believe this is not the expected behaviour. If the timeout is 3.0, connect() method should return something after timeout expires.

Comment: Did you try to set the `auth_timeout` parameter (see http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.2/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect)?